# How to break out of nested for loops in Julia

Tags: julia, nested-loops

I have tried to break out of nested loops in a quite ineffective way:

```
BreakingPoint = false
a=["R1","R2","R3"]
b=["R2","R3","R4"]
for i in a
  for j in b
    if i == j
      BreakingPoint = true
      println("i = $i, j = $j.")
    end
    if BreakingPoint == true; break; end
  end
  if BreakingPoint == true; break; end
end
```

Is there an easier way to do that? In my actual problem, I have no idea about what are in arrays `a` and `b`, apart from they are `ASCIIString`s. The array names (`a` and `b` in sample code) are also auto-generated through meta-programming methods.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do one of two things

have the loop statement (if thats what its called) in a multi outer loop

```
for i in a, j in b
    if i == j
        break
    end 
end
```

which is clean, but not always possible

I will be crucified for suggesting this, but you can use @goto and @label

```
for i in a
    for j in b
        if i == j
            @goto escape_label
        end
    end
end

@label escape_label
```

If you go with the @goto/@label way, for the sake of the people maintaining/reviewing the code, document your use properly, as navigating code with labels is breathtakingly annoying

For the discussion on the multi-loop break, see [this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5334)

Comment: There is really nothing more unreadable about the labels than with named `break` or with random booleans. As long as it's not misused, `@goto` and `@label` have an unwarranted negative reputation. Some programmers go so far to avoid them that they end up making code even less unreadable, as they replace a `@goto` with a boolean soup

Comment: I share your opinion, i like using labels, and rarely use boolean locks, as they feel clumsy

Comment: I like this answer, but had to chuckle at "I will be crucified for saying this..." :-D.  Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: That's what @goto is all about. Also in C.

Answer (score 19):

Put the 2D loop into a function, and do an early `return` when you want to `break`.